# Can you counter a spell with indestructible?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-indestructible

Can you counter an indestructible enchantment spell? For example, I cast [Kruphix, God of Horizons](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Kruphix%2C%20God%20of%20Horizons). Can you counter the spell with a spell like [Dissipate](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dissipate) while it's on the stack?

Comment: Don't forget to come back and vote for the answer if you found it useful.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you can.

The entirety of the rules for indestructible is that a creature with indestructible cannot be destroyed:

> 702.12a Indestructible is a static ability.
>
> 702.12b A permanent with indestructible can’t be destroyed. Such permanents aren’t destroyed by lethal damage, and they ignore the state-based action that checks for lethal damage.

To destroy a permanent is not related to countering a spell in any way.

To get even more technical, the spell does not have indestructible until after it resolves and becomes a permanent:

> 112.6. Abilities of an instant or sorcery spell usually function only while that object is on the stack. Abilities of all other objects usually function only while that object is on the battlefield. The exceptions are as follows:

(None of the listed exceptions apply here).

Comment: Ok, that clears things up. so anything on the stack is not considered on the battlefield so any abilities that is on the card won't activate until after the stack has resolved.

Comment: @user11582 Correct; in fact I was updating my answer with that clarification just now.

Comment: It comes mighty close to being a *characteristic-defining ability* [CR 604.3a] (which function everywhere, even outside of the game), but it's not.

Comment: @ikegami Was it a characteristic-defining ability a couple years ago, before they added the keyword?

Comment: Not if the definition of CDA was the same then. It has to modify colour, p/t and/or types

Comment: @Gendolkari Indestructible (and unblockable) before they keyworded (or removed) the word was weird because they looked like keywords but they were really just normal English words with their English definition.

Comment: Indestructibility has never been a characteristic, or alternatively, indestructible has never been a characteristic-defining ability. Characteristics are color, subtypes, power, and toughness [CR 604.3a(1)], at least in the current rules, but I don't think that has been changed for a long time, if ever.